# How do I get a List instance in List.js

Tags: javascript, listjs

I am initializing List.js (https://listjs.com/) in a file, and I need to get its instance from a different file. Say the first file contains something like:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var listObj = new List(foo, {...});
```

Now I want to add some items to the list from a different file. However I don't have access to the listObj variable, so I need to get this List instance somehow. This is how I imaging this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var listObj = List.getInstance(foo).add(...);
```

So the question is if there is a a way to get a List.js instance by element? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can pass the current list to window scope and access it in another file ...

Comment: thats something i wanted to avoid. i know other plugins make it simple like https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#flickity-data. was hoping something like this exists for list.js

Comment: on their documentation nothing of this type is listed but you can modify the plugin to do so...

Comment: my users are pulling it from npm so i cannot / dont want to modify the original files.